# $\infty$-Borel Determinacy?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

An *$\infty$-Borel set* is a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ which has an $\infty$-Borel *code* - a set $r$ coding the construction of $X$ via open sets, complementation, and well-ordered unions (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity-Borel_set). Under $ZFC$, every set of reals is $\infty$-Borel; however, this is not provable in $ZF+AD$ (it follows from a stronger axiom, $AD_+$).

Consider the following statement:

$$\text{$(*)$ Every $\infty$-Borel set (viewed as a game in the usual way) is determined.}$$

Clearly $(*)$ is independent (assuming consistency of large cardinals) of $ZF$, and is implied by $AD$. My first question is whether this is sharp:

> (1) Is $(*)$ strictly weaker than $AD$?

(I'm mostly asking this for actual implication - that is, whether $ZF+(*)\vdash AD$ - but I'm also interested in the question of their relative consistency strengths.)

EDIT: Andres' comments below completely answer this question. However, I'll leave the following paragraph from the pre-comments question, for the record:

*I suspect the answer is "yes"; however, the only approach I see is to start with a model of $AD$, and add an undetermined set of reals without adding any new $\infty$-Borel sets of reals. For example, if the $\infty$-Borel codes in a model of $ZF+AD$ could be reduced to individual reals, then starting with $V\models ZF+AD$ and adding an undetermined game via countably closed forcing would do the trick; but I don't see how to justify the hypothesis, and without it I don't know what to do.*

Assuming the answer to (1) is "yes," I also have the following question:

> (2) Is $(*)$ an interesting principle on its own?

Obviously this is somewhat vague; I am asking both about the principle $(*)$ itself, and the theory $ZF+(*)$ (the difference being, maybe $ZF+(*)$ happens to be some well-known theory but the specific sentence $(*)$ is not particularly interesting).

Comment: It is open whether $\mathsf{AD}$ and $\mathsf{AD}^+$ are equivalent; in particular, it is open whether $\mathsf{AD}$ proves that every set of reals is $\infty$-Borel.

Comment: If every $\infty$-Borel set is determined, then every set of reals in $L(\mathbb R)$ is determined, so at least we have equiconsistency.

Comment: I didn't know that it was still open whether $AD$ proved "all sets of reals are $\infty$-Borel," and it didn't occur to me that all sets of reals in $L(\mathbb{R})$ are $\infty$-Borel; your two comments (as far as I'm concerned) completely answer question 1.

Comment: If we assume $AD+V=L(\mathbb{R})$ then the pointclass of $\infty$-Borel set is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. This result is proved in Kechris, Solovay, Steel "$AD$ and the prewellordering property" in the new Cabal Volume II, appendix B.

Comment: @Carlo, I think that's exactly Andres' second comment. But thanks for the citation.

Comment: A silly question: is it obvious that there is an $\infty$-Borel set outside $L(\mathbb{R})$ (assuming, say, $ZF+AD+$"for every set of reals $A$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\not\subset L(\mathbb{R}, A)$)"?

Comment: Actually I think Andres may have been saying something a bit different than Carlo.  Suslin determinacy implies $L(\mathbb{R}) \models \mathsf{AD}$, as shown in the paper "The equivalence of partition properties and determinacy." Every Suslin set is $\infty$-Borel, so $\infty$-Borel determinacy also implies $L(\mathbb{R}) \models \mathsf{AD}$.  In the result Carlo mentions, $L(\mathbb{R}) \models \mathsf{AD}$ is the hypothesis, not the conclusion.

Comment: As for the "silly question" in your comment, the answer is yes (if you replace "obvious" with "true", that is.)  If $\mathsf{AD}$ holds and $V \ne L(\mathbb{R})$ then $\mathbb{R}^\sharp$ exists by a theorem of Steel and van Wesep, which implies that every $(\Pi^2_1)^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ set of reals is Suslin (due to Solovay, I think.)  A universal $(\Pi^2_1)^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ set cannot be Suslin in $L(\mathbb{R})$, and one can then show the existence of Suslin sets beyond $L(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I believe that my answer to [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165051/sets-that-are-not-infty-borel) is relevant for question 1.

Comment: If I understand that answer: start with a model $V$ of ZF+AD, in which every set of reals is Ramsey; now force with $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ to get a generic extension $V[G]$. Every set in the ground model remains determined, since the forcing adds no new reals, and every infinity-Borel set lives in the ground model, so is determined. So $V[G]\models (*)$. I don't see, though, how to show that $V[G]\models \neg AD$, which would be necessary to answer question 1. Is it clear that $V[G]\models\neg AD$?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this. Forcing with $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ adds a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$. Such an ultrafilter cannot have the Baire property (as a subset of the space $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$), so the existence of such an ultrafilter contradicts AD.